# How to find length of string using echo and wc command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying the following:

```
Len='echo $str | wc -c'
```

But I am getting this output:

```
'Echo $str|wc -c'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to use the backticks : `, not the single quote: ', eg. Len=\`echo $str | wc -c\`

Comment: Or `$()`. What you are looking for is called _command substitution_.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer using the quotes for command substitution, then you have to use the backticks : `, not the single quote: ', eg. :

```
Len=`echo $str | wc -c`
```

As others mentioned, you can as well use the `len=$(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
Len='echo $str | wc -c'
```

This will set the variable `Len` to the string `echo $str | wc -c` (it will not output anything).

The shell will not execute any of the commands in the string since it's not a command substitution.

To get the output of a command, use command substitution, `$(...)`:

```
Len=$( echo "$str" | wc -c )
```

In this case, it's also possible to use

```
Len="${#str}"
```

which is a lot quicker.

The parameter expansion `${#parameter}` will expand to the length of the value of `parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to Len variable the output of your command:

```
Len=$(echo "$str" | wc -c)
```